# Excel Change wording an color by date of month

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work as a bookkeeper for someone with a lot of bank accounts all which statements are released on various days of the week. I set up a conditional wording format to make it so Completed shows up green, Highlighted-yellow, and Still Need-red. My question is how can I format my sheet to make it so whenever say its the 11th of the month when a specific statement is release the word completed thats green will change to say Still Need - red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much leeway you have in the sheet.

What I would do is set up a "due date" column (as an actual date - less fiddling, and you actually can format it textually pretty close to the way it currently is), and change the task status to a formula based on due date and today's date. From there, you could either change the due month / year once the task is complete, possibly with a second date column for the previous date of completion, or set up a small vba sub & button to do so. Or switch to designated software, plenty of alternatives there, I imagine.

The exact rules required are unclear (in particular, that month only row would encompass special treatment), so I've put together a basic example to the best of my understanding.

```
Format for the date (tested on excel 2007; libre doesn't need \b or \n):
\Bala\nc\e\d up to MMMM DD
Formula for status:
C2=IF(B2=1,"Highlighted",IF(A2>=NOW(),"Completed","Still need"))
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Test]

The completed - still need status difference depends on the year - 2019 or 2020. Personally I'd display that, but it wasn't in your sample.